# Pyspark specify object type of variable

Tags: pyspark

I read the following data from a json file in pyspark:

```
{"positionmessage":{"callsign": "PPH1", "name": "testschip-10", "mmsi": 100,"timestamplast": "2019-08-01T00:00:08Z"}}
{"positionmessage":{"callsign": "PPH2", "name": "testschip-11", "mmsi": 200,"timestamplast": "2019-08-01T00:00:01Z"}}
```

The code looks as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StructField, StructType, StringType, IntegerType, DateType, FloatType, TimestampType

appName = "PySpark Example - JSON file to Spark Data Frame"
master = "local"
# Create Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName(appName) \
    .master(master) \
    .getOrCreate()

schema = StructType([
    StructField("positionmessage",
    StructType([
    StructField('callsign', StringType(), True),
    StructField('name', StringType(), True),
    StructField('timestamplast', TimestampType(), True),    
    StructField('mmsi', IntegerType(), True)
    ]))])

file_name = "data.json"
df = spark.read.json(file_name).select("positionmessage.*")
```

Now I want to remove the sting "testschip-" from "name". I  do as follows:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as follows:
df = df.withColumn("name", f.split(df['name'], '\-')[1]).show() # strips the string "testschip-"
```

How do I now make "name" an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cast to **`int`**.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
df = df.withColumn("name", f.split(df['name'], '\-')[1].cast("int")).show()
```